# Tkinter Application - How to reference and retrieve Entry value within a Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

All, this is the first time that I post question on StackOverflow.

I am writing a Tkinter application that allows user to enter stock information, and the window looks like this upon start up.

```
Label1  Label2  Label3
Entry1  Entry2  Entry3
```

If you want to add one more record, you could click a button and the window now becomes this:

```
Label1  Label2  Label3
Entry1  Entry2  Entry3
Entry4  Entry5  Entry6
```

Since I also wanted a button to delete row of record if not needed anymore, I use a piece of code from StackOverflow to append frame one after another.

Here is my question: After the user enter all necessary information and now want to perform calculation, I would like to transfer the `entry1`, `entry2`, `entry3`... into a data frame (or `dict`, or `list`) for storage. How could I refer to those `Entry`, by position, or other method?

The following code is used to add a line (`Frame`) or record upon each click of the <kbd>add record</kbd> button:

```py
self.framelist = []
self.framelist.append(Frame(frame))
self.framelist[-1].grid(row=self.i) #-1 is used to refer to the most recent 
                                    # element

entry1 = Entry(self.framelist[-1])
entry2 = Entry(self.framelist[-1])
entry3 = Entry(self.framelist[-1])
entry1.grid(row=self.i, column=1)    #self.i is just the arbitrary row number
entry2.grid(row=self.i, column=2)
entry3.grid(row=self.i, column=3)
```

---

I see the `framelist` has the type `list` and is the aggregation of `Frame`. Is there a way I could reference and retreat the value, for example, the first entry of the second frame?

Comment: You are already gathering multiple widgets into a list with the code `framelist`. Use a similar strategy for the `Entry` widgets.

Comment: *"reference ... the value, ... first entry ... second frame?"*: `self.framelist[1].grid_slaves()[0].get()`

Comment: @stovfl, you precisely solved my problem. This is exactly what I need!!! Thank you very much!!!